# android SupportMapFragment : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2

I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the line `map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);`. Strangely, this exception arises while running it some devices while in some it doesn't. How do I solve this?

```
public class MyMap extends ActionBarActivity implements
    RoutingListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
     SensorEventListener {

// private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
    }

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    map = mapFragment.getMap();


    map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
}
```

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
    map = mMap;

    mUiSettings = map.getUiSettings();
    mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);

    updateMyLocation();


}
```

Comment: extends FragmentActivity First

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on why and how does it solve the problem?

Comment: ActionBarActivity already extends FragmentActivity @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: Yes ,Mind it ActionBarActivity is deprecated .I here i used Appcompat instead ABA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`, I suppose you have to override this method `public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)`. Set your `mMap = googleMap` there and set all other listener there. Keep in mind that your Map object needs some time to be initialised, that's why they give you `getMapAsync` method.

Editted:

Please remove this from your `onCreated`

`map = mapFragment.getMap();
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);`

and put <s>them</s> `map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);` inside your `onMapReady()` after this line `map = mMap`. Please acknowledge when your map is initialized.

Comment: I am already overriding onMapReady. I have included it in the EDIT.

Comment: Well, **REMOVE** this

```map = mapFragment.getMap();
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
``` from your onCreated. As I said, your map is still null at this moment.

Comment: @Nguyen : So should I set my map to `mapFragment.getMap(); ` or `GoogleMap mMap`?

Comment: Oh my bad, ```map = mMap; map.setOnMy....```. Don't need to call your fragment anymore

Answer (score 0):

When you work with `GoogleMap` then it takes time to initialize. Sometimes it takes longer time in some devices than others.

To solve this issue, you should initialize the `GoogleMap` object with some delay. You can follow the below strategy:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable mapChecker = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            if (mapFragment.getMap() != null) {

                map = mapFragment.getMap();
                map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);

                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler.postDelayed(mapChecker, 500);
    }
};
```

Then from `onCreate()`,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);

    ..........

    handler.postDelayed(mapChecker, 500);

    ..........

}
```

Comment: Since new API have ```getMapAsync``` method and ```onMapReady``` callback method, you don't need this anymore. Take a look at my Answer.

Comment: since lately I didn't with `GoogleMap`, I was unaware of this callback. Now, I see this...its good.